# -bash: npm: command not found in Terminal with Docker MacOS

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I setup Docker on MacOS yesterday, and wanted to run npm and getting:
-bash: npm: command not found

What do I need to do to get it working okay? Thx.

Comment: Have you install the npm ?

Comment: What is the command you are using?

Comment: MacBook-Air:test-stable name$ npm install random-ext
-bash: npm: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm isn't installed on the image you're using.

You can do either of the following:

1. Install it via traditional means; dependent on the OS you're using.
2. Use an image, such as the [official node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) which will
   come with it pre-installed.

You could use #2 in a way such as:

```
 docker run node npm -v
```

Comment: @Patrick Please be sure to accept the answer if it answered your question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  I ran option #2 as shown:
MacBook-Air:~ name$ docker run node npm -v
Unable to find image 'node:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/node
85b1f47fba49: Pull complete 
...
Digest: sha256:7c9099e0f68242387d7755eaa54c287e16cedd3cca423444ca773794f5f1e423
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
5.5.1

But then after 
MacBook-Air:test-stable name$ npm install random-ext
-bash: npm: command not found

Why am I still getting command not found?

Comment: @Patrick - it looks like it worked! See the `5.5.1` that printed out? That's from running `npm -v`. When you ran `npm install random-ext` you're running that on your local machine, not on Docker. If you want to drop into a shell on the Docker machine, run `docker run -it node /bin/sh`

Comment: I saw the 5.5.1 and noticed it installed, but then npm install random-ext didn't run again and I got the same error.  Is "docker run -it node /bin/sh" the same as "npm install random-ext" then? Or how do I run it to install random-ext?  Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick; the last argument of that command is the command you are running in the container. In the first example; we ran `npm -v` and then **the container exits**. If you run `/bin/sh` as the command (With the `-it` flags) then you will run `/bin/sh` which will run the shell interpreter - and now you can interact with the system, but when you finish (crtl+c, type exit, etc.) then again - **the container exits**. If you want to install commands, do so within the shell; or better yet - codify it into a Dockerfile and build a new image so you can re-use it.

Comment: So I run "docker run node npm -v", then "docker run -it node /bin/sh" and get a new line. Then I try to install random-ext:
# npm install random-ext 
...and it says "added 18 packages in 6.797s".  Then how can I then execute another command after this on other files in the directory like "node --max-old-space-size=8192 server.js "?   Basically my question is how I can install random-ext and then run commands after on my computer? Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick - You should probably take a course on Docker; this is too much to explain on a single SO question.

Comment: Will do, thanks. Regarding "Install it via traditional means; dependent on the OS you're using.", how do I go about that? I went to install Homebrew to then install npm and get:
brew install node
-bash: brew: command not found
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac
Why command not found? Thanks.

Comment: Cheers for your time.  Got it going now.